# the rerun failed tests button is missing in android studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, testing

When I run unit tests, I need to be able to rerun just the failed tests but the "rerun failed tests" button is missing from the run toolbar. I only get the run and stop buttons. I can't see any way to set which buttons are in the toolbar and have found no one else with this problem. I don't want to spend 48 minutes running all 295 tests when only 9 failed!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Your Run tab shows Android tests running, not unit tests. 'Rerun Failed Tests' is only available for unit tests:
https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html